# HTML - PHP contact form email

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have searched here and in google how to make a contact form to work and I havent been able.

I downloaded a "php contact form" but I dont know how to make it work. I know there have been a lot asked question about this but please help me out. I am stuck here :/

This is the HTML code:

```
<form action="form-to-email.php" name="myemailform" method="post">
    <div>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name">
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="email" name="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" value="" placeholder="example@domain.com">
    </div>

    <div><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>

    <div class="code">
        <button><input type="submit" name='submit' value="Send"></button>
    </div>
    <i class="clear" style="display: block"></i>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the "free PHP form code" I downloaded from a website:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'myEmail@domain.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "myEmail@domain.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Do I need to do something in mysql or do something more at all?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you trying to run this from your own computer or hosted service?

Comment: first you have to check the mail() function is working fine with your server. If its fine, this will work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get any PHP errors? Do you not receive an email?

Comment: Please try to explain what you have done so far and what is your problem. Have you moved to script to a PHP server and tried to run it? What does it happen? What do you see?

Comment: Nobody spotted the syntax error `"Here is the message:\n $message".` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, debug it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- From a hosted service.

Comment: I dont get any errors.. but I dont recive any mail either when I test to email.. @Aculeo .

Comment: I dont get any errors.. but I dont recive any mail either when I test to email.. @entropid

Comment: You're not getting errors because you're not checking for them, and/or reporting is set to OFF on the service. There's a syntax error in your code, which the answers given below did not spot.

Comment: Here `"Here is the message:\n $message".` <= see the dot? That's supposed to be a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `"Here is the message:\n $message".` <= see the dot? That's supposed to be a semi-colon.

That, is the reason why OP's code is not working.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors, which it would have.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @AndresCeronMoreno You've very much welcome Andres; glad to have helped, *cheers*

Comment: nicely done funk forty, welcome to the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

everything looks correct, just add exit after redirect.

```
header('Location: thank-you.html');
exit;
```