# Google Recaptcha v2 With email form, gives http 500 Error

Tags: php, html, recaptcha, contact-form

Using an html form for a "contact us". This passes name, email, & message to a .php script and it works well. Add the Google recaptua v2 to this form gives a http 500 Error. This post and the code have been edited to reflect the KaplanKomputing tutorial suggested by Chris White.

You can visit the working form without recaptcha, and nonworking recaptcha here:
https://coinsandhistory.com#contact

The "Google site key" I'll call here "XXXX-Google-site" and "YYYY-Google-secret".

1st the contact form html, you don't need the css styling nor the stripslashes from the tutorial.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer> 
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/send-mail.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188436/html-php-contact-form- 
email/55962553 -->
<!-- https://kaplankomputing.com/blog/tutorials/
recaptcha-php-demo-tutorial/ -->
<form action="send-mail_SO2_recapt.php" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myemailform">
<div>
<span>Name &nbsp;</span>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name">
</div>
<div>
<span>Email &nbsp;</span>
<input type="email" name="web_email" autocapitalize="off" 
autocorrect="off" 
value="" placeholder="youremail@domain.com">
</div>

<div>
<span>messgae &nbsp;</span>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
</div>

<!--  Google v2 Recaptua Form   -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXX-Google-site"></div>
<br/>

<div class="code">
<button><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></button>
</div>
<i class="clear" style="display: block"></i>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the send-mail.php script. I called mine "send-mail_SO2_recapt.php".

```
<?php
/* error reporting, should rmv from working form */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST["name"];
$visitor_email = $_POST['web_email'];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
{
echo "Name and email are needed!";
exit;
}
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
echo "Bad email value!";
exit;
}

$url = "https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$data = array(
"secret" => "YYYY-Google-secret",
"response" => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
$options = array(
"https" => array (
"method" => "POST",
"content" => https_build_query($data)
)
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

if ($captcha_success=>success==false) {
echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>"; }
else if ($captcha_success=>success==true) {
echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";   }

// $email_from = 'info@coinsandhistory.com';//<== update the email address
$email_from = "$visitor_email";
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
"sender's email:\n $email_from\n".
"Here is the message:\n $message";

$to = "youremail@yourdomain.com";   //<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank_you_SO2.html');
exit;

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
?>
```

If you supply code samples, please indicate what form it is: eg html, php, javascript.  I can't believe I'm the 1st person to try to use a simple Google recaptua in a contact form but this question doesn't appear plainly anywhere.

Comment: Tutorial: https://www.kaplankomputing.com/blog/tutorials/recaptcha-php-demo-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks,  I edited my HTML and PHP code along the lines outlined by your example.  Although it's still not working, I feel I'm much closer.  I saw how to combine the recaptcha form data in with my original form data requesting name, email, and message. Also it shows where to add the "secret response" of the Google key and compare them.   However, I'm now getting a http 500 error.   Note, I changed all references in kaplankomputing's code from http to https.

Comment: Oh, for reference you can see the working plain form and nonworking recaptcha form here:   https://coinsandhistory.com/#contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see number of errors in your code. try the following code and see if it works, it is tested and working for me. it is not based on your followed tutorial and uses curl for verification instead.

Your biggest mistakes i think are that there is no *isInfected* function defined, *=>* in place of *->* and sometime *file_get_contents* doenst work on all servers.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Email</span>
    <input type="email" name="web_email" placeholder="youremail@domain.com" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Messgae</span>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <!--  Google v2 Recaptcha Form   -->
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
  <div class="code">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
//check form is submitted
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){

  // get values
  $error = '';
  $name          = $_POST["name"];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['web_email'];
  $message       = $_POST["message"];

  //Validate first
  if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) {
    $error = "Name and email are needed!";
  }

  //handle captcha response
  $captcha = $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $handle = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&response=$captcha");
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  $explodedArr = explode(",",$response);
  $doubleExplodedArr = explode(":",$explodedArr[0]);
  $captchaConfirmation = end($doubleExplodedArr);
  print_r($doubleExplodedArr);
  if ( trim($captchaConfirmation) != "true" ) {
    $error = "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
  }

  if( empty($error) ){ //no error
    // mail than
    $to = "youremail@mail.com";
    $email_subject = "New Form submission";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from ".$name.".\n".
    "sender's email:\n ".$visitor_email."\n".
    "Here is the message:\n ".$message;
    $headers = "From: ".$visitor_email." \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$visitor_email." \r\n";
    //Send the email!
    $mail_check = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    if( $mail_check ){
      // echo "all is well. mail sent";
      header('Location: thank_you.html');
    } else {
      echo "mail failed. try again";
    }
  } else {
    echo $error;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank very much!  I'm getting a new error however. This is   Array ( [0] => { "success" [1] => false )
You are a bot! Go away!

Comment: I should mention that I'm still just learning javascript and haven't gotten to functions yet.   On the php file, if I change the if (trim) test to:  if ( trim($captchaConfirmation) != "false" ) {
    $error = "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";    then the Recaptcha always suceeds regardless of whether the box is checked or not.  I did go back to Google and made sure I copied the data site key and the secret directly from Google.  They appear correct in the original form tho.

Comment: if you are getting  Array ( [0] => { "success" [1] => false ), that means google is not passing u as human. i added the print_r($doubleExplodedArr); line to display the raw response from recaptcha itself. i dont think there is error in code. maybe try submittin on same page than means leave the form action="" empty, and write the php code on same page.

Comment: by any chance if you are really frustrated by this, feel free to email me at aspnetusername@gmail.com.

Comment: I've added more print statements and have gotten: Array ( [0] => { "success" [1] => false ) { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response", "missing-input-secret" ] } falsefalse
You are a bot! Go away!    ........  Previously I had a lot of problems sending mail even without the recaptcha.  I finally found it was due to my ISP which had disabled the send_mail() without telling me.  I suspect that there are still server problems?  It seems that Google isn't even getting any site-key code "missing input secret" "missing site-key". I'll look at my server logs.

Comment: good, looks like you are going in right direction. i tested the the whole code again which i provided u with another recaptcha key, it is working perfectly. so it is definitely some other out of this code problem which is preventing it from working.

Comment: I may have found a problem.  In your line:    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&response=$captcha");   I am not quite sure what to insert.  I have a new Google site Key which is 40 characters. I'll call this SITEKEY-XXXX instead of writing the full 40 chars.  Also my secret key I'll call SECRET-YYYY.   The SITEKEY-XXXX  only I put in the html part.     In your php code curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=SECRET-YYYY&response=$captcha");    I was just putting "SECRET-YYYY" before.  Still no permutation works. All return "you are a bot".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which worked for me.  I'd like to really thank Galzor as his answers helped me a lot.  The base Code I got from Code Geek and I added stuff here to add in the form.  This format hopefully eliminated the confusion on exactly what to include in the Google "SITE-KEY" and "SECRET-KEY" as it gets them as variables before processing them in a string.  These are actually 40 character strings. The sucessful captcha goes to a landing page.

This is the HTML send-mail_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- form goes in the body of HTML  -->
<form action="send-mail_form.php" method="post">

<div>
<span>Name</span>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name" required>
</div>

<div>
<span>Email</span>
<input type="email" name="web_email" placeholder="youremail@domain.com" required>
</div>
<div>
<span>Messgae</span>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
</div>

<!--  Google v2 Recaptcha Form   -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE-KEY"></div>
<div class="code">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this will be the called send-mail_form.php.   I won't bother with showing the thank_you_SO2.html here.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$web_email;$message;$captcha;
// check form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['web_email']) ){

// get values
$name=            $_POST["name"];
$visitor_email=   $_POST['web_email'];
$message=         $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) {
$error = "Name and email are needed!";
}

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}

if(!$captcha){
echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
exit;
}

$secretKey = "SECRET-KEY";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// post request to server
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . 
urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
// should return JSON with success as true
if($responseKeys["success"]) {
// echo '<h3>Thanks for contacting us</h3>';

// mail then
$to = "youremail@yourdomain.com";
$email_subject = "CG Recaptcha Form2 submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from ".$name.".\n".
"sender's email:\n ".$visitor_email."\n".
"Here is the message:\n ".$message;

//Send the email!
$mail_check = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body);
if( $mail_check ){
// echo "all is well. mail sent";
header('Location: thank_you_SO2.html');
}
else {
echo '<h2>You are a spammer ! Go Away</h2>';
}
}
}
?>
```

There are some unneccesary items, the error checking at the top can probably be removed.  Also will the Google site verify will work with https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=.... ?  Actually on testing it seems to fail sometimes without the www so perhaps best to keep it.

Comment: i am glad it worked out. nice job. hope u learned alot in process

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Galzor.  Your article on php email headers was quite useful.  Here is the ref:  https://www.formget.com/how-to-stop-email-spam/   The code I added was   $headers .= "From: myemail@mydomain.com\r\n";   Note the space & period after $headers.  It required this as the ISP's servers were not trusting mail from an unknown source.

Comment: By now Recaptcha v2 is obsolete but still free & working from Google.  Added a 2-question Quiz with answers from my website.  This has stopped All spam 100%.  Works in conjunction with the Recaptcha.